# Swift C Interop: How to avoid absolute paths for modulemap headers?

Tags: swift, cmake, clang

I am working on building a swift wrapper over a C library (ROS2 RCL), using C interop features. I’m currently using CMake with module maps to achieve this functionality. Currently, my modulemap looks something like this:

```
module CRcl [system] {
  header "/opt/ros/foxy/include/rcl/rcl.h"
  link "rcl"
  export *
}
```

This currently builds just fine on my system. However, using the absolute path is a pretty poor solution, as it requires modification for different os’s or custom install paths. I would prefer for it to be automatically discovered.

Ideally, I’d imagine something like this:

```
module CRcl [system] {
  header "rcl/rcl.h"
  link "rcl"
  export *
}
```

where I don’t specify an absolute path, instead directing the compiler to find the header via a CLI arg or environment variable.
I have seen various guides for working with frameworks in XCode, but nothing that would be relevant for my setup on Linux. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: @A Tyshka did you find some workaround/solution for this?

Comment: @CAMOBAP I stopped working on it a few years ago and at the time, no. Possibly this has changed but I'm not sure.